# How to tag your pages to find your scraped content?

Tags: web-scraping

With several bots scraping pages on our site, I wanted to know how I could tag the content, to later search for it - find out where the scraped content ended up?

I set a unique HTML comment on the pages, but that probably won't get scraped.

All the links on our pages are JavaScript links, that route through a JS function - that may help the rest of our content from getting scraped.

Is there a way to tag the links on the site for this purpose?

Comment: can you give an example of what you trying to do, its a bit confusing.

Comment: _With several bots scraping pages on our site_ - do you mean you have bots that scrape on your behalf in order to add content to your site, or that your site is being scraped by someone else's bots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use specific utm tags in the links you could accomplish this. Obviously, you will need to make it something that is very unique. UTM tags are used often for advertising but they could be repurposed. Here is a quick explanation on them:
http://www.intownwebdesign.com/google-analytics/google-analytics-utm-link-tagging-explained.html

My opinion, it still would be difficult to track web scrapers just by looking for links. Often scrapers scrape away tags, links, etc. You should probably look at ways to stop them from scraping your content in the first place, but thats my biased opinion.

For full disclosure, I am the cofounder of [Distil Networks](http://www.distilnetworks.com) so we push people to block bots.